# Laravel Spatie translation package not working for Raw Queries and join operations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-translatable

Used this [Spatie/laravel-translatable](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable)
package i achived my localization with ORM queries like (Article::all();). But when i use raw query or join operations(DB queries), it shows the raw json from database.

Article.php

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\Translatable\HasTranslations;

class Article extends Model
{
    use HasTranslations;

    public $translatable = ['name'];
}

?>
```

Controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App;
use App\Article;
use App\User;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return $result = DB::table('articles')->get();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and my solution (the only way I found) was define an accessor to get the attribute translated:

```
public function getNameAttribute($value)
{
    return json_decode($value)->{\App::getLocale()};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting them trough the `DB` facade, therefor you get raw data from the database via [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries).

To get the translations you should query the `articles` table through the `Article` model making use of [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent) instead.

```php
public function index()
{
    return Article::get();
}
```

If you want to join some data by hand, you can:

```php
Article::query()
    ->join('table', 'table.article_id', 'articles.id')
    ->get();
```